# Ошибка подключения к SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

> Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient; // в этом пространстве имен находится поставщик данных для MS SQLServer

using System.Data;



namespace CBS.ADO_NET.ConnectionStrings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True";               //строка подключения
            // string conStr = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True"; 
            // string conStr = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True"; 

            // Следую инструкциям строки подключения следует найти на локальном компьютере экземпляр SQL Server  с именем SQLEXPRESS, 
            // поискать каталог ShopDB и попытаться получить доступ к источнику данных через доверительное подключение, 
            // используя для этого вашу учетную запись Microsoft Windows

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr); // создание экземпляра класса SqlConnection


            

            try
            {
                connection.Open(); // открытие физического подключения к источнику данных 
                Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close(); //закрытие физического соединения с источником данных
                Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Цитата

Если я все правильно ввел, то шибка 40 не удалось открыть подключение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так какой текст ошибки?

Comment: Вы аам сервер установили? Существует ли он на локальной машине? Покажите что да в менеджмент студии

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит аам сервер?

Comment: Ошибка 0 Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое соединение

Comment: Почитал https://www.sql.ru/forum/758546/setevoe-podkluchenie-error-26 там советуют найти некоторые строчки, но поможет ли это и что потом со строчками этими делать не понятно

Comment: Также почитал здесь https://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread1856148.html предлагается экранировать слэш, но тогда выдает error 26 ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра

Comment: В строке соединения укажите ваш сервер. WIN.... Initial catalog IVAN

Comment: Вы соединились не по адресу "." У вас имя сервера другое. И название базы

Comment: вы имеете ввиду SQLEXPRESS заменить на имя компьютера, а каталог на Ivan?                          
       string conStr = @"Data Source=.\WIN-9VNS32J8479;Initial Catalog Ivan; Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Каталог = ivan любой параметр через =

Comment: правильно ли я понял?

Comment: string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479-IVAN-SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = ShopDB; Integrated Security=True";

Comment: или через слэш правильно?

Comment: string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = ShopDB; Integrated Security=True";

Comment: И если у меня при входе в Windows пароль это как-то влияет на подключение?

Comment: Я в имени сервера не видел sqlexpress

Comment: "Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog = ShopDB; Integrated Security=True" либо "Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479;Initial Catalog = IVAN; Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подправьте на

"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog = ShopDB; Integrated Security=True" либо "Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479;Initial Catalog = IVAN; Integrated Security=True"